Selenium manager unable to install driver in my company's vpn
Selenium manager is unable to install webdriver and is throwing error as:
raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for MicrosoftEdge using Selenium Manager.

Any help will be appreciated, I am stuck I this from very long.
Without vpn it is able to load browser and perform task successfully.

Selenium Version: 4.16
Python version: 3.10.4
Edge Version: 124.0.2478.67

My code:
from selenium import webdriver

# Initialize the Edge WebDriver with the options
driver = webdriver.Edge()

# Navigate to a website
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

# Print the title of the page
print("Title of the page:", driver.title)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()


In case you can't manage to get access to internet from the organisation network, you always have the option of not using SeleniumManager. Just download and set the driver path manually. See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/78365546/7598774

In your case, you'll either need to ask your IT team to whitelist the URLs that are being used to resolve the webdrivers or you'll require them to share the details of a proxy which will allow your requests to access the urls to download the driver.
You can refer to the answers written here -> Webdrivermanager is unable to download driver due proxy not apply when working on company vpn
For Python, you'll need a custom http client to act as a proxy to your requests. A sample of which is written in the pyDoc : https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/
